# Get value from javascript to php and fill div with php grid(that is in php file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my javascript code :

```
  $(document).ready(function()
{

 $("li").click(function() {

    var childid = $(this).attr("id"); /*  this works(gets id of clicked li)  */

    if(childid)
    {
        var child = childid.split(';;;');

        $('#Grid').load('../Grid/FillWithGrid.php',{"name" : child[1], "family" : child[0]});    /*   I think problem is here */
    }
 })

})




  <div class="Grid" id="Grid">
  This is index.php where it must be pasted
</div>
```

This is FillWithGrid.php:

```
  <?PHP
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 require_once("../Grid/conf.php");

 $conn = mysql_connect(PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME,PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME,PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD);
 $CHName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]);  /*ERROR : Undefined value*/
 $CHFamily = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["family"]);   /*ERROR : Undefined value*/
 mysql_close($conn);

if($CHFamily & $CHName)
{
   $query = "select * from `view_marks` where `name` = '$CHName' and `family` =  '$CHFamily' ";

   $dg1 = new C_DataGrid($query);
   $dg1->enable_advanced_search(true);

   $dg1 -> display();

 }
 ?>
```

1)I can't get childname and childfamily from javascript. It says 'undefined name' and 'undefined family'. So It doesn't get value from javascript.  ---  RESOLVED!!!

2)It is showing blank page when I click on li...

Have anyone got any idea. Please help

Thanks!!!

Comment: It contains  name;;;family it is splitting successfully. I alerted it and it worked problem is where I marked, I am sure but I can't resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide data for load function, then the request method would be a POST instead of GET. Use $_POST in php to get the value instead of $_GET as shown below.

```
 $CHName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);  
 $CHFamily = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["family"]);
```

For further information on load(), refer [this](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I changed it and it worked now, THANKS very much, BUT it is locating in blank page and never stopping locating there.

Comment: "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." - you'r right :-)

Comment: @user2971569 i couldn't get what u mean by "locating in blank page and never stopping locating"? Could you please explain a bit

Comment: It doesn't shows anything. Only blank page... and it is loading and loading. I want this grid to appear without refresh but it refreshes and shows only blank page.

Comment: @user2971569 What does your li contain? Kindly provide that html snippet. Does your php return the response? You can check it through developer tools

Comment: I want to import into div whole gridview that returns php file.  My li have id which I want to get, then insert this id into php which is selecting from table where (I will use id value here) and creating from that gridview.

Comment: @user2971569 that is clear. But what am asking is, has your POST request received a response? How long is the response taking? Any jsfiddle link where we can take a look at its behavior?

Comment: Can we continue tacking in private chat? I'll send you link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48770/discussion-between-user2971569-and-rakhi4110)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in query

```
$query = "select * from `view_marks` where `name` = '$CHName' and '$CHFamily' ";
```

it should be

```
$query = "select * from `view_marks` where `name` = '$CHName' and `family` = '$CHFamily' ";
```

If I'm wrong i dont know what alse it can be ;-)

~Cheers

Comment: Sorry this was error which is because I haven't rewritten code correctly...  But in code there isn't such error. I will edit my question.

Comment: But error isn't there... I am getting warning that my variables are undefined so it isn't getting values...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use console.log() to check if values are passed, example:

```
$('#Grid').load('../Grid/FillWithGrid.php',{"name" : child[1], "family" : child[0]}, function(responseText){console.log(responseText)});
```

inside FillWithGrid.php:

```
print_r($_GET);
die;
```

Maybe it can help... if not - check HTTP requests/responses in browsers Developer Tools.

Send me a link (via priv) to problem, maybe I can solve it.

~Cheers

Comment: print_r($_POST['name'].$_POST['family']);
die;          I wrote this in fillwithgrid.php.  I did everything  As you sad and it is showing name and family correctly. But I want to get grid in index php not name and family and it isn't working... thanks for reply.